# Transform nosql data (firestore) to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures, relational-database

I previously used Firestore to store the data of my app. I now want to change my backend which comes with an sql database.

I have the following structure:

[image: structure]

and want to transform this into an sql schema. This structure represents a *vocabulary* in my app. One *vocabulary* belongs to one *list* and has one to many *original meanings* and one to many *translations* for this original meanings.

But I'm struggling to outline this relations.

This is my current approach, but I'm not happy with it:

[image: approach]

So I have one entity for the *vocabulary* itself which stores the connection to the *list* and the *score* (how often was this vocabulary answered right or wrong in a test). Also I have the entity *word* which simply represents one word (like "store" or "shop" from the above example).

Than there is the junction table *vocabulary_word* which connects one vocabulary with the corresponding words and a type (enum = "original" or "translation").

**But now I'm wondering how to check for duplicate vocabularies? and how to ensure that there is always at least one original and at least one translation for a vocabulary?**

Is this a usecase for stored procedures (or the responsibility of my backend) or is this schema just bad and there is a better structure?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your time.

Comment: "... to change my backend which comes with an sql database..." -- Nowadays, both relational and NoSQL databases use SQL for querying -- the latter kind of an oxymoron, but heck. SQL by itself shouldn't be a cause for migration, unless there are specific limitations of the query language you are not mentioning.

Comment: It seems like aggregation queries are not supported nativly from firestore (you need work a rounds for this) also I want to have more control over my backend and I also need some cronjobs. For this reason I want to change to a laravel backend with an sql database.